# Computing with the Monster

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The [Monster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) **M** is the largest of the finite sporadic groups that arises in the [classification of finite, simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) in mathematics.

**M** can be realized as a (very large!) set of `196882 X 196882` matrices with nothing more than entries of 1's and 0's, so long as we compute arithmetic as follows:

`1+1=0`
`1+0=1+0=1`
`1*1=1`
`0*0=0`
`1*0=0*1=0`

I have two simple questions for the reader. What is the minimum amount of bytes needed to store a single matrix? What is the computational cost (i.e., in FLOPS) of a single matrix multiplication in the most efficient implementation?

Thanks,
Andrew.